# How to search for functions in module?

Tags: python

I want to have a search function like a man page inside a Python module.

Is there a built-in or module function to search a string/wildcard char in function name/class name/object name or function of class?

e.g. `find(get_*)`?

This would find all `get_*` functions, such as `get_height`, `get_weight`, `get_area`, `get_volume` as well as `square.get_area`,`rectange.get_area`
or have a `find(get?int`) to find `get_int`, etc.

I can have a list in `help(module)` but there is too much clutter and no search function I can find.
If not, how can I write a function to do the same?

Comment: dir() will return a list of all the stuff in the current namespace; if I'm dealing with something with a lousy API documentation, I will often do def find(name): for i in dir(); if i.find(name) != -1: print i

Comment: @Foon It does not answer the wildcard requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using `re`, for simple matches of the type you've given, use [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch).  That provides much **friendlier** matching.

```
def find(value, pattern="*"):
    from fnmatch import fnmatch
    return [x for x in dir(value) if fnmatch(x, pattern)]
```

Then:

```
>>> import os
>>> find(os, "u*")
['umask', 'uname', 'unlink', 'unsetenv', 'urandom', 'utime']
>>> find(os, "?n*")
['environ', 'initgroups', 'uname', 'unlink', 'unsetenv']
```

Comment: Friendlier and much more limited matching.

Comment: @martineau of course, as noted ... "for simple matches of the type you've given".  I imagine most users of such a function would like it to operate like the normal wildcard matching they use in a shell.

Comment: Regexes for simple matching are fairly simple, so not too un-friendly to master. `fnmatch` was designed to be mimic the kind of wildcard matching with filenames that many are familiar with from using them on the command-line.

Comment: How do I get rid of AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fnmatch'

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni  Make it `fnmatch(...)` not `fnmatch.fnmatch(...)`

Comment: @donkopotamus Althought, it did work, I still cannot find functions bound to classes. It could find only the global functions. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module to do this as illustrated below. You need to learn how to write regular expressions to use it, but that's extensively documented. For a good start see the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) in the documentation.

```
import re

def find(module, regex):
    return [name for name in dir(module) if re.match(regex, name)]

# Sample usage

import some_module
print(find(some_module, r'get_\.*'))  # Search for things prefixed with "get_".
```

Answer (score 0):

So... From what I can glean from your post, you want to be able to find and return a list of all the functions within your module that matches a given pattern. Sounds to me like a job for `re`!
Here's my python.

```
import re
def find(the_module,regex=''):
  match = re.compile(regex)
  matched_values = []
  for i in dir(the_module):
    if match.search(i):
      matched_values.append(i)
  return matched_values
```

Comment: Note that, while this answers the wildcard requirement, it also requires you to be familiar with regular expressions.